# Android SDL13: Center screen (Using Android 2.3.3)

Tags: android, sdl

I want to use the compatibility mode. Thus every device displays at 480x320.

SDL does left align the screen always. But for larger screens like tablets it really makes sense
to center the screen.

Currently I patched SDL_compat.c like this:

```
#ifdef __ANDROID__
window_x=SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED;
window_y=SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED;
#endif
SDL_VideoWindow =
SDL_CreateWindow(wm_title, window_x, window_y, width, height,
window_flags);
```

But that doesnt help. Screen is still displayed left aligned. Any help pls!!!

EDIT: My code is calling SDL_SetVideoMode()